# Qt Creator Run Environment Ignored

Tags: environment-variables, qt-creator

I am building a console application in **Linux Ubuntu**. Setting environment variables in **Qt Creator**'s **Run Environment** panel is not working, both if I switch on the flag "**Run in terminal**" or not. It looks like they are just ignored. If I export those variables outside Qt Creator, in a plain terminal, and then run my console application, everything is fine.

I am using Qt Creator 3.5.1.

Comment: Not really an answer, but I have noticed a lot of oddities when working with Qt Creator like this. There was some setting I set to get it to finally work. Let me see if I can remember it.

Comment: So I am booting my machine with Qt Creator on it, but are you sure yo set the variables in the appropriate run mode? If memory serves me correctly , there are several you can choose from (i.e. release, debug, profile, etc.). Setting variables in one and running another would cause the issue you are having.

Comment: @MrJman006 you are right, but currently I only have one project setup, which is basically "release with debug info"

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot to your question showing where you are setting your environment variables?

Comment: also how are you accessing the variables?

Comment: I can't do screenshots since is corporate code. I am setting those variables using the panel Projects -> Run Settings -> Run Environment. I do not know how those variables are accessed, project is just too big. What I can tell you is that if I place the exports in .bashrc, then exec qtcreator from the a terminal, and press run once the project is loaded, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I think you are setting the variables in the correct place, but just in case here is a screen shot of where I set mine.One thing to note which we already discussed in the comments is what "kit" you are running. In the screenshot below, I only have one kit set up, but if you have more than one, you have to choose the appropriate kit by clicking on the little monitor icon in the bottom left of Qt Creator.

[image]

Then in code I use the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Get the variable or a default value if the variable is not set.
    // Qt abstraction that should work cross platform.
    QString s = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment().value("VAR_ONE", "");

    // Get variable in platform dependent way.
    char * s2 = getenv("VAR_ONE");

    // Print out the results.
    qDebug("%s", s.toStdString().c_str());
    qDebug("%s", s2);


    return a.exec();
}
```

If you are doing all of this and still having issues, I would try making an new empty console application and see if the above works to narrow down if the problem is with your Qt Creator in some way or if the project you are working in has some setting that is off.